# Context menu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu

In C# windows form application, I want to add item to context menu so that I can check or uncheck that item in context menu. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is. Just change the [`CheckOnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checkonclick.aspx) property of your `ToolStripMenuItem` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible:
[MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem(VS.80).aspx) and then the Checked property